# Storing @property functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

Is it possible to store a `@property` function inside a variable?

Imagine we have the following code:

```
class I:
  def __init__(self):
    self.i = 0

  def get_i(self):
    return self.i

a = I()

f_i = a.get_i

print(f_i())

a.i = 3

print(f_i())
```

I save the function get_i inside a variable and use it. The output is as expected:

```
0
3
```

Now lets look at the same code, but this time with an `@property` function:

```
class I:
  def __init__(self):
    self.i = 0

  @property
  def get_i(self):
    return self.i

a = I()

f_i = a.get_i
```

Now `a.get_i` is not the function anymore (It is the value 0). Is there any way to still store the function inside the f_i variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a `property` is that it is called on access. You'd have to bypass the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to prevent this.

You can do this by accessing the `property` object on the class instead:

```
f_i = I.get_i
```

then bind it to an instance later on:

```
print(f_i.__get__(a))
```

Or you could access the `fget` getter function on the property object, bind it to `a` to create a bound method, and store the result for later calling:

```
f_i = I.get_i.fget.__get__(a) 
print(f_i())
```

Accessing the property on the class still invokes the descriptor protocol, but in that case `property.__get__` returns the property itself.

Demo:

```
>>> a = I()
>>> I.get_i
<property object at 0x10efceb88>
>>> I.get_i.__get__(a)
0
>>> I.get_i.fget
<function I.get_i at 0x10efc3048>
>>> I.get_i.fget.__get__(a)
<bound method I.get_i of <__main__.I object at 0x10efd32e8>>
>>> I.get_i.fget.__get__(a)()
0
```